# Adding a span to bootstrap label with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper

How do i add a span to a bootstrap form label generated using bootstrap form rails gems.

This is what i've tried so far with no luck:

```
= bootstrap_form_for resource, url: wizard_path, method: :put, layout: :horizontal do |form|

 = form.select :cover_type, form.object.cover_types, {include_blank: true, label: "Cover Type <span class=fa fa-question-circle hidden-lg hidden-md></span>".html_safe}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with this?

```
= bootstrap_form_for resource, url: wizard_path, method: :put, layout: :horizontal do |form|
  = form.label 
    Cover Type 
    %span.fa.fa-question-circle.hidden-lg.hidden-md
  = form.select :cover_type, form.object.cover_types, {include_blank: true}
```

Any reason why you wouldn't just put the label before the `select` element?

Comment: The indentation is off somewhere, I'm not able to test it out for you at the moment. . .  Try messing with the spacing of the lines after the `= form.label` line.  Maybe check with the haml documentation.